# How can I disable autogrowth in SQL Server wide

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a database server that some databases with restricted users are in use in the database. I need to restrict users to can't change `.MDF` and `.LDF` autogrowth settings. Please guide me to restrict the users.

I think there is two way to get this access:

1. Disable autogrowth in databases
2. Limit the maximum size of MDF and LDF

But I couldn't find any option in Management Studio to do them server wide and also get access from users.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can execute following [ALTER DATABASE command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-parallel-data-warehouse) which sets auto growth option to off for all databases using undocumented [stored procedure sp_Msforeachdb](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sp_Msforeachdb-example-list-all-database-files.aspx)

for single database (Parallel Data Warehouse instances only)

```
ALTER DATABASE [database_name] SET AUTOGROW = OFF
```

for all databases

```
EXEC sp_Msforeachdb "ALTER DATABASE [?] SET AUTOGROW = OFF"
```

Although this is not a server variable or instance settings, it might help you ease your task for updating all databases on the SQL Server instance

By excluding system databases and for all other databases, following T-SQL can be executed to get list of all database files and output commands prepared can be executed

```
select 
    'ALTER DATABASE [' + db_name(database_id) + '] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N''' + name + ''', FILEGROWTH = 0)'
from sys.master_files
where database_id > 4
```

[image]

To prevent data files' autogrow property to be changed, I prepared below [SQL Server DDL trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-tools/log-drop-table-in-sqlserver-database-using-ddl-trigger.aspx) once I used a DDL trigger for logging DROP table statements.
Following trigger will also prevent you to change this property, so if you need to update this property, you have to drop this trigger first.

```
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_filegrowth
ON ALL SERVER
FOR ALTER_DATABASE
AS   

declare @SqlCommand nvarchar(max)
set @SqlCommand = ( SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') );


if( isnull(charindex('FILEGROWTH', @SqlCommand), 0) > 0 )
begin
    RAISERROR ('FILEGROWTH property cannot be altered', 16, 1)   
    ROLLBACK  
end
GO
```

For more on DDL Triggers, please refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers)

Comment: thanks about your quick reply. but when I do it the users can edit their own database. is there any option to restrict users to avoid access to this option?

Comment: Thank you for feedback masoud, I added a DDL trigger which prevents updates on AutoGrow property of any database. Maybe it can help you. You can add additional filters to exclude master, or tempdb, etc according to your requirements